# WSO2 ESB endpoint using cached backend name

Tags: wso2, endpoint, wso2-esb

We can see calls going from ESB to backend system old Ip instead of the new IP. For example

Wso2 ESB Endpoint configured as: somebackend.com

If we do nslookup to see the IP of the system.

```
$nslookup somebackend.com
10.20.30.40
```

If we trace the traffic from ESB using tcpdump with host as "somebackend.com" then calls are going to old IP of the system (somebackend.com) i,e, 50.60.70.80 instead of new IP 10.20.30.40

Is the name/Ip/DNS Name is cached anywhere in the WSo2 ESB.? 
Any suggestions, please resolve this. 
Below is the endpoint file configured.

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="conf//endpoint/endpointname">
    <property name="System-Name" value="Backend" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <http uri-template="somebackend.com"
         method="get">
    <suspendOnFailure>
           <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
           <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
           <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
           <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
      </markForSuspension>
   </http>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in your /etc/hosts file whether you have wrongly mapped the old IP to the domain name (somebackend.com)? It might be a possibility because AFAIK ESB does not cache IP. Maybe restarting the ESB server would also help.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR WSO2 ESB does not cache endpoint IPs. Can you run a traceroute command on "somebackend.com" from the ESB node and check whether how DNS resolves from your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Wso2 will store the connection details in connection pool and re-use the same connection details for the next calls instead new one. We added below property before making a call to the endpoint to initiate a fresh new connection for each call which resolved our issue.

FYI: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/HTTP+Transport+Properties

Thanks for the support guys.